# Авто покрутка и авто очистка input-a

Tags: html, css

У меня такой код чат-комната:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<?php
session_start();
 ?>
<script>

function getText() {

    var $a =    document.getElementById('text').value;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST' , 'chatdb.php',true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send('chat='+$a);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xhr.responseText){
            //  document.getElementById('chatarea').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
                                    }
                }
                    }


function setText(){

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST' , 'chatFetch.php' , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    //  alert(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById('chatarea').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }

    }
    setInterval("setText()",1000);


setInterval("users()",1000);





</script>
<?php

include_once('config.php');
                //  echo        $_SESSION['email'];
                //  echo    $_SESSION['password'];
            echo    $_SESSION['name'];




if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user
SET user_status = '0'
WHERE user_email = '$_SESSION[email]';");
session_destroy();
header('location: practice.php?logout_successfully=<span style="color:green">You have successfully Logged Out.</span>');

    }

?>
<form action="">
<input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout">
</form>

<style>

</style>
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
        //session_destroy();
        header('location: practice.php');
        }

 ?>


 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading" id="accordion">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="chat">






                                                                <div id ="chatarea">
</div>

                                           </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button onclick="getText()"class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                                Send</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Каждый раз когда пишешь сообщение,нужно бывает прокрутить самим что бы увидеть отправленное сообщение и после отправки сообщения,в input текст остается нужно бывает стереть самим как сделать чтобы после отправки автоматически стерались сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в событие обработки запроса.

```
document.getElementById('text').value = '';
var chatArea = document.getElementById('chat');
chatArea.scrollTop = chatArea.scrollHeight - chatArea.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Я добавил в функцию getText() не сработало

Comment: Никак не сработало

Comment: А куда именно добавить скажите

Comment: После `document.getElementById('chatarea').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;`

Comment: Не как нет,пишу сообщение очищается

Comment: После того как пишешь сообщение остается на месте chatarea нужно бывает самим крутить вниз я хочу это вот как в инстаграме как везде само сделало

Comment: А что приходит в responseText? Там нету элементов с id, которые уже есть на странице?
В консоли ошибки есть?

Comment: Вместо `var chatArea = document.getElementById('chat');` наверно нужно `var chatArea = document.getElementById('chatarea');`, если я правильно понимаю, в общем то, что нужно прокрутить.

Comment: Запустите в консоли `document.getElementById('text').value = '';` - должно почистить текст (попробуйте и до отправки и после).
Ошибки вылетают в консоли?

Comment: Я код добавил и есть ошибка: Cannot read property scrollheight of null и текст очищается